# How to merge two data tables on base of the ID column in dataset

Tags: vb.net, datatable, dataset

I have a dataset with two datatables, defined as below:

```
Datatable: Suppliers
SupplierId SupplierName SupplierDUNS

Datatable: SupplierPortal
SupplierId SupplierName SupplierDUNS
```

I have to bind the below columns to the grid

```
Suppliers.SupplierId
Suppliers.SupplierName
Suppliers.SupplierDUNS
SupplierPortal.SupplierDUNS
```

How can I merge both datatables based on the ID? I am using VS2005 so I'm unable to use Linq.

Comment: `provide me in vb.net code` SO is ***not*** a code generator.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

*"Merge the specified DataTable with the current DataTable."*

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Data set designer.cs and send a true value to merg function

```
this.Merge(ds, **true**, global::System.Data.MissingSchemaAction.Add);
```